# Import xml file in to my sql database using php

Tags: php, xml

I'm using simple_load_file in PHP read XML tags and import XML file database error occurred

how to import XML file in database using php

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');

echo "starting";

//mysql connection
$con2 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con2)  {  
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
}

$selectdb = mysql_select_db("weberpdemo", $con2);
if (!$selectdb)  { 
    die('Database not used: ; ' . mysql_error());  
}

echo "connected to DB<br /><br />";



    examples given $mess = simplexml_load_file($filename);
echo "xml loaded<br /><br />";

$messageid = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->messageid);
$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->mobile);
$time = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->time);
$latitude = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->latitude);
$longitude = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->longitude);
$status = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->status);
$speed = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->speed);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->address);
$direction = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->direction);
$runningodo = mysql_real_escape_string($mess->runningodo);

echo "xml parsed<br /><br />";

//insert into databse                     
mysql_query("INSERT INTO xml (messageid, mobile, time, latitude, longitude, status, speed, address, direction, odometer)
VALUES ('$messageid', '$mobile', '$time', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$status', '$speed', '$address', '$direction', '$runningodo')")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: they are a lot of examples how to read xml. one of them is [this](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Introducing-SimpleXML-in-PHP-5/1/)

Comment: how to import xml file in mysql table? any answer'

Comment: dude, you have examples how to read tags in link i posted!

Comment: dont do it down vote?

Comment: how does your xml looks like? in your code you dont call any root  element (or repeating one).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you are trying to archive with the data after importing into the database.

- If you just want to save the data and extract it as is, you can serialize the data before saving.
- If you need to index or directly access the stored XML data, you should use load_xml.

Comment: im using load file but how to read tags?